# Did OCaml get any Serious Promotion last few Years?

Tags: ocaml

Did you hear something about any corporate investments or enlargement of OCaml community? (not F# please)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

[The number of developers contributing to the OCaml code base at XenSource grew to 18](http://ocamlnews.blogspot.com/2008/11/stunning-slides-about-growth-of-ocaml.html) (Nov 2008). XenSource was subsequently sold to Citrix for $500,000,000.

[The number of full-time OCaml developers at Jane St grew beyond 30](http://ocamlnews.blogspot.com/2009/01/jane-st-capital-expand-their-ocaml.html) (Jan 2009).

[Cilk Arts sold their Cilk++ tool chain, which is partly written in OCaml, to Intel](http://www.drdobbs.com/cpp/218900367) (Aug 2009).

Intel, Jane St, Citrix, CEA, OCamlCore, SimCorp and MLState paid to join the [CAML Consortium](http://caml.inria.fr/consortium/) in the past 3 years alone (now 11 members in total).

[Coherent Graphics shipped their first product](http://www.coherentgraphics.co.uk/cpdf.html), written in OCaml.

The world's largest people search engine, [Wink](http://wink.com/), was launched (and it is written almost entirely in OCaml).

[MLState released their first product, Opa](http://ocamlnews.blogspot.com/2010/01/mlstate-release-their-first-product-opa.html), which is written entirely in OCaml (Nov 2009).

And, of course, Microsoft released the world's first mainstream functional programming language F# in April 2010 and it is a close relative of OCaml. That had the knock-on effect of boosting interest in OCaml considerably.

Answer (score 8):

The [Caml Consortium](http://caml.inria.fr/consortium/) has 10 members, each paying fees of 3000 EUR/year to INRIA for support and development of OCaml. Jane Street Capital is of course a member, and the OCaml summer of code they organize is in addition to their participation in the consortium.

Answer (score 4):

[Jane Street Capital](http://www.janestcapital.com/) has [OCaml Summer of Code](http://ocaml.janestreet.com/?q=blog/78#) every year. Other then that, I really don't recall. You should check the [archives of the OCaml mailing list](http://groups.google.com/group/fa.caml/topics), there would definitly be announcements there of anything like you've mentioned.

Answer (score 1):

Does [Jane Street Capital](http://www.janestreet.com/technology/ocaml.php) count?